# Unity : Post Processing without playing

Tags: unity, post-processing

I have attached a post processing profile to my main camera for bloom and other similar effects. I know that when the game is running, the post processing works as I can see its effects. However, is there a way for me to see my post processing effects **without** having to run the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the Camera that has the `Post Process Layer` component attached is indeed your *Main Camera*. This is the camera that is used for rendering the scene view.

Under Unity terms, the main camera is the first encountered GameObject that is tagged **MainCamera**. So ensure there isn't any other such tagged camera that is found by Unity firstly.

Hope this helps!